# Assign either of value that exists or not null RuleInput($date = (this["startDate"] || this["startingDate"]))

Tags: java, drools, rules, rule-engine, mvel

Inside RuleInput there may be either "startDate" or "startingDate" , I need to assign value to $date variable either of the value that exists.

Something Like,

```
RuleInput($date = (this["startDate"] || this["endDate"]))
```

What would be the correct syntax for drools?

Answer (score 0):

The correct syntax is to have two rules.

```
rule "With start date"
when
 RuleInput( $date: startDate != null, endDate == null )
then
  // do something
end

rule "With end date"
when
  RuleInput( $date: endDate != null, startDate == null )
then
  // do something
end
```

Since the rules are mutually exclusive you won't accidentally fire both.

---

As a side note, you used an interesting syntax in your question:

```
RuleInput( $value: this["foo"] )
```

The `this["key"]` syntax is very old, but it works with objects that have a method of the form `public Object get(String key)`. It's most commonly used with `Map`. You'd hardly ever want to use it in modern drools (and you don't want to pass Maps into rules in general because they serialize very poorly.)